# .js file execution in .html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript.

I am trying to create an interactive graph using javascript. I found a good source code but I cannot find a way to execute this code.

This is the graph I am trying to create
http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/BarChart/example1.html#

and here is the source code
http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/BarChart/example1.js

I saved the source file and created a .html file (Notepad++) as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/example1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am just getting a blank page in Internet explorer. Please Help !

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Also, have you downloaded the JIT library and the accompanying CSS files that go with it? Doesn't look like you've included them.

Comment: No, Just a blank page without any error messages

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: -1 You should do some research before asking and try to ask a more specific question. This is like asking for someone to make you a tutorial, sorry.

Comment: All your data is inside a function called `init()`. Where do you call that function?

Comment: What if you include the Jit library and the accompanying CSS files that go with it?

Comment: Internet Explorer? If you were to use Firefox or Chrome, you can see the error that javascript throws by pressing F12 and going to Console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the jit-yc.js file too.

As can be encountered in the HEAD tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jit-yc.js"></script>
```

Simply download the file and put the script tag in your head and all can works perfectly. :)

Comment: That would only work if they user has jit-yc.js two level's down in their directory structure. Also, if you look in the source you need to set where the bar chart will be displayed.

Comment: @ajtrichards Yes, i know. I just copied the code from the page of example, awaiting the user to fix the path correctly. :) (yes, i'm really waiting this)